# Jbuilder not working with gem rails-api

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, jbuilder, rails-api

I'am trying rails-api gem with jbuilder and i can't seem to make it work

Here is a sample of my rails-api controller / jbuilder views

Gemfile

```
gem 'jbuilder'
```

Controller app/controller/users_controller.rb

```
 def show
  @user = User.find_by(id: params[:id])
 end
```

View app/views/users/show.json.builder

```
json.content format_content(@user.id)
```

According to the Jbuilder documentation this should work fine but still nothing is returned.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Since i found no proper answer on that issue i just left rails-api and built my own api from a brand new rails app. All is working great now.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I know that the original issue had probably been resolved. Nevertheless I had the same issue and finally found an answer.

Since rails-api is stripped down version of rails some functionalities are missing (in this case implicit rendaring of views) and we need to add them explicitly.

Simplest solution is to add ActionController::ImplicitRender to ApplicationController

```
# app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  include ActionController::ImplicitRender
end
```

Comment: In Rails 5 you'll probably also need to add `include ActionView::Layouts`

Comment: Also, make sure to uncomment " gem 'jbuilder' " in Gemfile! Wasted a few hours finding this. :(

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you misnamed your jbuilder view.
It should be `app/views/users/show.json.jbuilder` instead of `app/views/users/show.json.builder`.